# maximize 3-variable linear function [version 2.0]

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

This problem came up when I was trying to solve a bigger, probabilistic problem. So at the end it boils down to this: how can we maximize the function

$f(x_2,x_3,x_4) = \frac{18}{100}\frac{x_2}{6}\frac{13}{10}\frac{13}{10} + \frac{42}{100}\frac{x_3}{4}\frac{13}{10}\frac{13}{10}\frac{13}{10} + \frac{35}{100} \frac{x_4}{1} \frac{13}{10}\frac{13}{10}\frac{13}{10}\frac{13}{10}$

subject to:

$\frac{x_2}{6} + \frac{x_3}{4} + \frac{x_4}{1} = C \gt 0$
$x_2 \ge 0$
$x_3 \ge 0$
$x_4 \ge 0$

I need some explanation/reference for this particular problem (I hope to understand this one now), and also some general reference for this type of problems (maybe I will need some more time to understand that part). Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836565/maximize-3-variable-linear-function-version-1-0 I think I made a mistake in version 1.0 of this question so I corrected it here in version 2.0. I think of deleting 1.0 soon but it has some valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a question of feasibility.
If the point where the equality constraint and the Function meet is in the right half plane that point is the solution.

So all you need is to find the intersection of the hyperplanes.